# Position as function of time given velocity with respect to position.

Tags: calculus, integration

I have been able to solve this problem in a very clumsy way that I don't think is using the right steps.  In particular, I'm not sure where the assignments of the arbitrary constants are rightly applied.

Question:
Find the position $s$ as a function of $t$ from the given velocity $v = ds/dt$. Evaluate the constant of integration so as to have $s=s_0$ when $t=0$.

$$v = \sqrt{2gs},\ \ \   (g = \text{constant}).$$

My attempt and issues with the problem has involved:

$$v=\frac{ds}{dt}=\sqrt{2gs}$$

$$s^{-1/2} ds = (2g)^{1/2} dt$$

$$d(2*s^{1/2}) = d(t*(\sqrt{2g}) + C$$

Now, I can convert that to:

$$s=(1/2)gt^2 + C$$

And when $s=s_0$ at $t=0$,

$$s=(1/2)gt^2 + s_0$$

Substituting the right side of the original equation $V=\sqrt{2gs}$ doesn't seem to work. On the other hand, I can see that

$$v=\frac{ds}{dt}= \sqrt{2gs} = gt$$

so I am thinking there may be an approach using that equality to determine $C$ as well.

**UPDATE:**

This is the stated answer, but I’m not sure of the steps for getting the $ t\sqrt{2gs_0}$ term into the equation:
$$s = s_0 + t\sqrt{2gs_0} + \frac12gt^2$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Hi, I've made some edit to fix the formatting. You can click "edit" to see what I have done. For more information see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Hi John - Thanks so much for helping me out and cleaning that mess up!  Much appreciated.  I'll check out the link you provided.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We have

$$v=\frac{ds}{dt}=\sqrt{2gs} \implies \frac{ds}{\sqrt s}=\sqrt{2g}\, dt \implies 2\sqrt s=\sqrt{2g}\, t+c$$

---

Edit to help the OP step by step:

$$\implies 4s=2gt^2+2c\sqrt{2g}\, t+c^2 \implies  s=\frac12gt^2+\frac12c\sqrt{2g}\, t+\frac14c^2$$

and from $s(0)=s_0$ we obtain $\frac14c^2=s_0 \implies \frac12 c=\sqrt{s_0}$ and therefore

$$s=\frac12gt^2+\sqrt{2gs_0}\, t+s_0$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  I've gotten this far (see my edited question above), but substituting the right side of the equation into the original equation for V does not seem to work.

Comment: @JMSE Sorry I thought it was $s(0)=0$. I fix that.

Comment: You have an algebraic error in your move from $\frac {ds}{dt}= \sqrt{2gs}$ to $\frac {ds}{\color{blue}{s}} = \sqrt {2g}dt$. $$\frac {ds}{\color{blue}{s}} \text{ should be }\; \frac {ds}{\sqrt s} =\sqrt{2g}\;dt$$

Comment: @amWhy Yes you are absolutely right! that's a bad typo, Thanks I fix!